# opportunity currencyisocode equal to account

Tags: apex, trigger, multi-currency, currency

```
trigger Accountcurrency on Opportunity (before insert) {
 Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>();
 for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
   {
       accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
   }
List<Account> accs=[select id, OwnerId,currencyisocode from Account where id in :accIds];
Map<Id, Account> accById=new Map<Id, Account>();
   accById.putall(accs);
   for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
   {
    opp.currencyisocode=accById.get(opp.AccountId).currencyisocode;
}
}
```

This is the trigger which i wrote .when i created a opportunity related to account it has to  take currency currencyisocode  from account.I don't see any mistake on my trigger but the currencyisocode remains same it is not taking from account

Comment: we are using multiple currency.According to user locale it is taking currency.when i created a account with EURO.And user locale is INR.while creating a account It will show INR ,i will change to EUR .when i create opportunity from account it is taking INR .it is not not taking EURO.

Comment: Your code is Ok, you'd had other trigger or WF that is changing. Easy to check putting this line: `opp.currencyisocode='EUR';`

Comment: Code looks perfect. Check for workflows, triggers and other processes that might change it.

Comment: Are you really sure you want this, though? If someone enters an oppty with currency with a different isocode, you're going to overwrite it, and the value will change without notifying the user who entered it.